# Returned Function becomes a Promise and can no longer be called

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this function:

```
async listenProgrammStatus(uid, programmId, onUpdate) {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.firestore().collection('Users').doc(uid).collection('ProgrammStatus').doc(uid + programmId).onSnapshot(function (doc) {
        console.log('DOC', doc);
        if (doc.exists) {
            const status = doc.data();
            status.id = doc.id;
            onUpdate(status);
        }
    })
    console.log(unsubscribe)
    return unsubscribe;
},
```

And I call it like this:

```
const unsubscribeStatus = db.listenProgrammStatus(this.user.uid, this.programm.id, (status) => {
    console.log('STATUS', status);
    this.status = status;
})
console.log('UNSUB', unsubscribeStatus)
this.unsubscribeStatus = unsubscribeStatus;
```

How ever the unsubscribe function I returned doesn't seem to work after I returned it. calling `unsubscribeStatus()` won't work.

`unsubscribe()` works in `listenProgrammStatus` but when I return the function, it seems to become a Promise and I can't call `unsubscribeStatus ()`.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I would respectfully suggest that you thoroughly read the documentation of `onSnapshot`, because I've the feeling you misunderstand how it works. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#onsnapshot

Comment: Sorry but why do you think this? My problem was that the function was async ( on accident ) but I can't see what should be wrong with the way I use onSnapshot

Comment: If I am not mistaken, there is no reason to “promisify” an onSnapshot: it is used to attach a listener for DocumentSnapshot events and does not return a Promise. And by calling unsubscribe() you detach the listener so that the event callbacks stop getting called. This function does not return a Promise neither. I had the feeling you were using it as e.g. an asynchronous get() method.

Comment: Oh ok, I did not intend to return any Promise, but I didn't noticed I had it marked as async and therefore it returns a Promise.

Comment: I got you! Happy coding and nice WE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `async` keyword has two effects:

- It makes the function return a Promise that resolves as whatever value you use with the `return` keyword
- It allows you to use `await` inside the function

If you don't want a promise, don't mark the function as `async`. You aren't using `await` in it anyway!

Comment: Damn I can't believe I didn't sport this my self... Thank you!